# how to export a live python dataframe to excel +

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, export

Good morning guys, I am facing a problem having made a python prog where the dataframe is exported to excel. This works well when there is no live data in the dataframe but the moment the live data through websocket is activated there is an error message.The live data is stock market data and my question is there a way to freeze the dataframe and export it to excel for that moment or is there any other way?+

Comment: What is the error message, and what is your code? We need more specific details in order to help with your problem :)

Comment: error message The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: thank you Josh, will put up code too